# To embed or not embed?

Tags: mongodb, schema, normalization, denormalization

I'm trying to figure out which schema design I should use.

*(These are example documents, the actual documents contain more properties)*

**Embedded:**

```
{
   _id: ObjectId(),
   title: "trolo",
   subs: [
      {
         owner: refUserId
      },
      ...
   ]
}
```

I indexed on: `ensureIndex({ "subs.owner": 1 })`

**Normalized:**

```
Collection A:
{
   _id: ObjectId(),
   title: "trolo"
}
Collection B:
{
   parent: refId,
   owner: refUserId
}
```

I indexed on: `ensureIndex({ owner: 1 })`

I've run some `benchRun()` tests on the different models. But the result is very surprising.

**Embedded query:**

```
ops = [
    {op: "find", ns: t.getFullName(), query: { "subs.owner": someUserId }}
]
```

**Normalized query:**

```
ops = [
    {op: "find", ns: t.getFullName(), query: { owner: someUserId }}
]
```

**benchRun script:**

```
for (x = 1; x <= 128; x *= 2) {
    res = benchRun({
        parallel : x,
        seconds : 5,
        ops : ops
    });
    print( "threads: " + x + "\t queries/sec: " + res.query);
}
```

Output:

Embedded:

```
threads: 1       queries/sec: 11331
threads: 2       queries/sec: 16764.6
threads: 4       queries/sec: 21587
threads: 8       queries/sec: 25198.6
threads: 16      queries/sec: 24717.6
threads: 32      queries/sec: 24707.4
threads: 64      queries/sec: 25813.8
threads: 128     queries/sec: 30785.4
```

Normalized:

```
threads: 1       queries/sec: 8.4
threads: 2       queries/sec: 13.2
threads: 4       queries/sec: 16.4
threads: 8       queries/sec: 17.4
threads: 16      queries/sec: 18.2
threads: 32      queries/sec: 20.8
threads: 64      queries/sec: 27.4
threads: 128     queries/sec: 39.6
```

Why is the normalized model so much slower? I would have expected it to be the fastest.

**UPDATE**

Here is what `.explain()` has to say about my queries.

**Embedded**

```
> db.embedded.find({"subs.owner":ObjectId("516ea63322f2a93c4fef8542")}).explain()

{
        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 5,
        "nscannedObjects" : 5,
        "nscanned" : 5,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 5,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 5,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {

        },
        "server" : "localhost:27017"
}
```

**Normalized**

```
> db.collectionB.find({owner: ObjectId("516ea63322f2a93c4fef8542")}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor owner_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 76625,
        "nscannedObjects" : 76625,
        "nscanned" : 76625,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 76625,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 76625,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 91,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "owner" : [
                        [
                                ObjectId("516ea63322f2a93c4fef8542"),
                                ObjectId("516ea63322f2a93c4fef8542")
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "localhost:27017"
}
```

Comment: did you try using `explain` on your queries to see what's going on?

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now :), not sure why I didn't think of it earlier. But my normalized query has `indexOnly:false` so I'm reading http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/

Comment: Others have noted recently that `indexOnly:false` can be very confusing and difficult to `explain` [sigh] :)  .

Comment: It's scanning 76000+ documents in the "normalized" case? Hmm. That doesn't seem right at all.

Comment: 76625 is the document count, I believe. But now that you mention it it does seem a bit high, need to check my build script :). Anyway since it uses the owner index it shouldn't need to scan the entire collection right?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you expect normalized to be faster? With embedded, the document is stored in a single location on disk. With one disk seek the entire document can be brought back. If it is normalized, it is spread across the disk and this means 2 disk seeks to get the information. Depending on the speed of disk and the sectors that the needle has to go to, it is inevitably going to be slower than the embedded document model.

Comment: Because it has to search nested documents. I noticed that once I did a $unwind and $match the performance tanked to 0 queries/sec on the embedded model.

Comment: No because the bsonspec allows nested subdocuments to be skipped over